# How to change the layout of log messages from GlassFish 3.1 in Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo)

Tags: java, logging, glassfish-3, eclipse-indigo

I have Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo) installed with GlassFish plug-ins, which allows me to start/stop the server, deploy/undeploy, etc. It also integrates the server.log from domain1 of GlassFish to the Console view in Eclipse so I can see what is going on.

However, the messages in the log have a standard layout that doesn't show which class is sending the message. How do I change the layout of the log messages that show in the console view in Eclipse?

Thanks in advance for your help!
- Vítor

Comment: Since searching the web and asking this question so far didn't produce any answers, I decided to investigate the GlassFish plug-in source and it seems that the log format is hardcoded in a specific class of the plug-in (i.e., can't customize it). So I came up with a hack to change it. If anyone is interested, see my blog: http://disi.unitn.it/~vitorsouza/blog/hacking-eclipses-glassfish-plug-in-to-show-better-log-messages/

Comment: Raise a bug report on this, please.